# Setting classpath in idea for running unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, classpath

I am using `openCSV` jar to work with csv present in my parser project, now I want to unit test my parser and for that I get call pass it to object of my parser class so that I can go ahead and do parsing.

Now am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader`, `openCSV` jar is already present in the project but now if i try to run unit test, i get above mentioned error.

How can i set project classpath in intellij idea so that I can run unit test having reference to all dependent jars.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have different modules for your project and unit testing than you need to add dependency of that .jar also in your unit testing module.

For e.g. When I am making project using IntelliJ I create modules.
for e.g. I have two modules: `main` and `test`. Than I create libraries for my main module and for my test module and add them into modules dependencies.

I am using IntelliJ 10.5.4 so the path would be: File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> main -> Dependencies -> Add -> then I select created library.

Also you can add module dependencies to other modules and use their classes.

Hope this helps.